# Serilog logger not writing logs to appropriate logs

Tags: c#, serilog, serilog-filter

I am trying to write to separate log files depending on where the method is run.

I have the Serilog configured in my AppStartup class

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
            .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("DataProcessing.DataManagers.HistoricalEquityDataManager"))
            .WriteTo.File(LogFileTemplate.HistoricalDataLogFileTemplate.Replace("{machineuser}", Environment.UserName)))
        .WriteTo.File(LogFileTemplate.TradeActivityLogFileTemplate.Replace("{machineuser}", Environment.UserName))
        .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
            .CreateBootstrapLogger();
```

When methods from the class DataProcessing.DataManagers.HistoricalEquityDataManager are run I want them to log to a different file (noted in the config builder).

The logs from those methods are still writing to the file in the file noted in this codeline. They ARE NOT being run from the filtered logger.

```
.WriteTo.File(LogFileTemplate.TradeActivityLogFileTemplate.Replace("{machineuser}", Environment.UserName))
```

Comment: All log messages are going to be written to `.WriteTo.File(LogFileTemplate.TradeActivityLogFileTemplate.Replace("{machineuser}", Environment.UserName))` - just like all log messages are going to be written to Seq. You're not filtering anything from those two sinks. 

If the filtered log isn't working correctly, you might consider using the `Matching.FromSource<T>()` overload instead of specifying the fully-qualified name as a text string.

Comment: I tried that overload, still doesn't write there

Answer (score 0):

The `Matching.FromSource()` methods require that the `SourceContext` property be present in the log context. See [the source code for Matching.cs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Filters/Matching.cs).

Adding the `SourceContext` property is achieved by creating a "local" `ILogger` instance in the constructor for each class and logging to that local instance.

```
public class Foo 
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    
    public Foo() 
    {
        _logger = Log.Logger.ForContext<Foo>();
    }

    public void SomeMethod() 
    {
         _logger.Information("Hello world");
    }
}
```